# Rebuild Page in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-pageview

I want the same detail page to be regenerated when the user clicks the next or previous content button at the bottom of the blog detail page. My solution:

```
Visibility(
                            visible: widget.index < _listLength ? true : false,
                            child: TextButton(
                              onPressed: () {
                                Route route = MaterialPageRoute(
                                    builder: (c) => DetailPage(
                                          index: widget.index + 1,
                                          detailDataList: widget.detailDataList,
                                        ));
                                Navigator.push(context, route);
                              },
                              child: Text(
                                'Sonraki Yazı',
                                style: TextStyle(color: mPrimaryColor),
                              ),
                            ),
                          )
```

Problem: Detail Page creates a new page every time it is created, which means extra unnecessary cost. How can I create the detail page with the new data in the list?

```
Route route = MaterialPageRoute(
                                    builder: (c) => DetailPage(
                                          index: widget.index + 1,
                                          detailDataList: widget.detailDataList,
                                        ));
```

In summary: When the user clicks the next content button at the bottom of the detail page, the same page should be rebuilt with the next data in the list, but the new page, not over the previous page. How can I do that?

Comment: instead of that just update your widget.index and reload the page.

Comment: I'm trying right away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
                           Visibility(
                            visible: widget.index < _listLength ? true : false,
                            child: TextButton(
                              onPressed: () {
                                widget.index = widget.index + 1;
                                setState((){});
                              },
                              child: Text(
                                'Sonraki Yazı',
                                style: TextStyle(color: mPrimaryColor),
                              ),
                            ),
                          )
```

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't work

Comment: what issue you are facing ?

Comment: Maybe it was a problem with the emulator, it's working now, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you have many options :
1  - you can update the page instead of push a page over the current page .
2  - you can use popAndPushNamed instead of push , this function will pop the current page and push another one.

Comment: I have not used the second method before, I will investigate.